# MVC Confused about where to put logic.

Tags: java, model-view-controller

So I am currently modelling a MVC type system, total noob to this pattern and I'm trying to figure out a couple of things but one thing particular I can't figure out how to handle.

In my system I create e.g a Customer Class & DAO with CRUD functionality which I understand (to an extent  ) etc...

I have a table in my database that log's data, this table is never accessed by the user only the extent that they can view calculations/results from the data in this table.

How do I represent this in my design, I have no need for CRUD functionality only just to return results from SQL (e.g Select average/total/ etc).

I obviously need to access the data but I'm not sure if I need a class that models the table or just somewhere to put the logic.

Any help or pointers would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

View (JSP or JSF that displays the Model) -> Service Layer (business code that starts the transaction, uses DAO etc, populates the Model) -> Data access layer (your doa and data mapper here) -> DB

- Make sure your Model reflects what user wants.
- Perform Transaction demarcation in service layer
- Perform DB access and data mapping in the Data access layer

**NOTE: None of this requires Spring. Pure Java EE is more than enough.**

Answer (score 0):

If u want strict MVC then u must create class that represents your table, and dont access directly to table.

PS this class may contain only one method, that is ok.

Comment: We should model data reflecting what user wants. Not how we store.

Comment: So this table may contain a large amount of records, e.g 1 million + , would I just model the table in a class but then in the Access Object instead of having CRUD functions I could have the functionality I want, e.g getMonthAverage() , getWeekTotal() etc .. ?

Comment: It's quite confusing where to put this logic because as a beginner I am not using any framework etc, for simple classes like the customer class I am just modelling the Class itself and then DTO and then DAO with a simple CRUD interface. Moving onto the logic  where I am encountering the issues ..? Where to put it ..?

Comment: here how i see this:
1)user send reques -> controller

2)controller -> model (model may return any data as u want, but don't break mvc pattern, for example model->getMonthAverage() return int, or model->getSome() retuns object list that u can access)

3)controller <- model

4)view <- controller

Comment: _for simple classes like the customer class I am just modelling the Class itself and then DTO and then DAO with a simple CRUD interface_
u can imagine that ur class is like DAO but only with "read" interface with no create, write or update.

Comment: @dark_gf I'l just give you this as a for instance to make sure I am going down the right path , I can create a class called for instance "UsefulData" with attributes "averageOne" , "averageTwo" and methods getAverageOne() , getAverageTwo ... When I create a DAO for this I ignore the CRUD interface and use my getAverageMethod()'s , this way i can ignore how my table is designed and only access the data I want .?

Comment: yes you are right, DAO task is to provide abstract access to database without knowing how it works or how it is designed.

Answer (score 0):

You should use some framework to implement MVC, like Struts or Spring. For your scenario, Struts will be good and business logic should be in the normal java classes.

Front controller should send the request to model classes with business logic and tables should be implemented using Java Beans.

Comment: Pankaj - What you said is true in early 2000. For simple to mid level applications, plain JEE is more than enough. For e.g. JSF2 is a complete MVC framework in itself.